# How to eliminate the indent in column definitions?

Tags: tables, minipage, parindent

A really Latex beginner but adventurer is writing, then the question might look strange. I tried [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152582/why-is-the-minipage-indented-on-the-left/) though.
I have defined the new column style but I do not know how to remove the indentation in each table cell. In this simple example how can I get rid of the gap between the "Number of terms" and the left vertical line of the table?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\parindent = 0pt
\the \parindent

\large{TEXT}

 \newcolumntype{R}[2]{
>{ \minipage[c][#1][c]{#2} }
l <
{\endminipage}
}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular} {|R{1cm}{.2\textwidth} R{1cm}{.2\textwidth} R{1cm}{.2\textwidth} R{1cm}{.2\textwidth}}

        Number of terms & $\sin(\dfrac{\pi}{6})$ & $\epsilon_t$ & $\epsilon_a$ \tabularnewline 
        1 &  0.52360 &  0.047198 &    \tabularnewline 
        2 & 0.49967 & 0.00065164 & 0.047880 \tabularnewline 
        3 & 0.50000 & 0.0000042652 & 0.00065590 \tabularnewline 
        4 & 0.50000 & 0.000000016261954 & 0.00000428144 \tabularnewline

    \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Even though I have set the `\parindent` to the zero value.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

add `@{}` between `|` and `R`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\parindent = 0pt
\the \parindent

\large{TEXT}

 \newcolumntype{R}[2]{>{\minipage[c][#1][c]{#2} }
l <
{\endminipage}
}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular} {|@{}R{1cm}{.2\textwidth} R{1cm}{.2\textwidth} R{1cm}{.2\textwidth} R{1cm}{.2\textwidth}}

        Number of terms & $\sin(\dfrac{\pi}{6})$ & $\epsilon_t$ & $\epsilon_a$ \tabularnewline 
        1 &  0.52360 &  0.047198 &    \tabularnewline 
        2 & 0.49967 & 0.00065164 & 0.047880 \tabularnewline 
        3 & 0.50000 & 0.0000042652 & 0.00065590 \tabularnewline 
        4 & 0.50000 & 0.000000016261954 & 0.00000428144 \tabularnewline

    \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can control how much space is inserted between the vertical line and the cell content: `@{ }` will insert a single space, `@{\hskip<width>}` will insert a specific width, say 5pt or whatever.

Comment: there is no paragraph indentation in tables.  what is seen in the example in the question is the `\tabcolsep` at the beginning of the first column.  the initial `@{}` overrides that setting, as shown in this answer.

Comment: Actually that's right. However if you set `\tabcolsep` zero. It applies for every cell. @barbarabeeton

Comment: @Reza -- but you don't want to apply it to every cell -- that would leave no space at all in the last row.  that makes it very hard to read.

Comment: @barbarabeeton No I definitely don't. It exactly messes the last row. I control the width of the cell by the second argument in the `\newcolumntype{R}[2]`. I can either `\tabcolsept=0pt` and control by argument #2, or just remove the space by `@{}` in the beginning of the first column. Either way the width of the cell is controlled by the definition.

Answer (score 4):

Your question is not very clear to me. From your MWE I only see unnecessary complication in table design. So see, if the following solution can help you:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}% option showframe serve only to show page layout, 
                                % in real aplication had to be removed
\usepackage{array}

\parindent = 0pt

\begin{document}
\the\parindent

\large{TEXT}

{\renewcommand\tabcolsep{7.5mm}
    \begin{tabular} {|@{} l l l l @{}}
Number of terms & $\sin(\dfrac{\pi}{6})$ & $\epsilon_t$ & $\epsilon_a$ \tabularnewline
1 &  0.52360 &  0.047198 &    \tabularnewline
2 & 0.49967 & 0.00065164 & 0.047880 \tabularnewline
3 & 0.50000 & 0.0000042652 & 0.00065590 \tabularnewline
4 & 0.50000 & 0.000000016261954 & 0.00000428144 \tabularnewline
    \end{tabular}
}
%\end{center}
\end{document}
```

It gives:

[image]